# Java Enum: Take Multiple Values at a Time

Tags: java, enums, multiple-value

Correct me if I'm wrong:

1. enum is a type
2. an object of some enum type can take 1 and only 1 enum value at a time

Now I've got a question:
Assume I've defined an enum(or some other data structure that's suitable for the task; I can't name it, because I'm looking for such a data structure to accomplish the following task) somewhere in my java program. If, somehow, I have an enum(or some other data structure) object in main(String []) and I want it to take multiple values of the enum(or some other data structure), how do I do it? What's the suitable data structure I should use if it's not enum?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a simple array, any collection from the core [java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) API would also do the job (like lists or sets, it's a bit more convenient than using arrays), but probably what you are after is [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

```
enum Monster {
    GOBLIN, ORC, OGRE;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final EnumSet<Monster> bigGuys = EnumSet.of(Monster.ORC, Monster.OGRE);

        for (final Monster act : Monster.values()) {
            System.out.println(bigGuys.contains(act));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes-- the advantage of an EnumSet is that it has built-in optimisations so that e.g. a set of low-valued enums gets implmented as a bitmask.

Comment: yeap, exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks for the code segment.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for either:

- `java.util.EnumSet`
- varargs: `method(MyEnum ...values)`
- A simple array: `MyEnum[]`

I usually prefer the `java.util.EnumSet` myself, it's easy to work with and can quickly check if it contains a certain valaue etc. It's a subsitute for `or` of flags as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing so much candidates, Pulsar!